# programmatically add label to panel

Tags: .net, vb.net, label

I am trying to add a label programmatically to a panel. When I add the labels with same Y axis and stagger the X the only the first labels show. When I stager both the X and Y they all show. I moved the Panel1.Controls.Add(labels(i))to another area not shown. Below I commented the intY_location for all labels to show on the same Y axis.

```
        Dim labels(100) As Label


    For i = 0 To 100

        labels(i) = New Label
        Panel1.Controls.Add(labels(i))
        '   labels(i).Font = 1
        '   Label1.Font = New Font(labels(i).Font.Name, labels(i).Font.Size + 10, labels(i).Font.Style)

    Next i



            For i = 0 To 10
            '     Panel1.Controls.Add(labels(i))
            intX_Location = (intX * i) '+ (intSpacer * i) + (intPixel_Width / 2) '//Offset
            intY_Location = 50 '(i * intY) + (intSpacer * i) + (intPixel_Width / 2)
            labels(i).Text = "i"
            labels(i).Visible = True
            labels(i).Location = New Point(intX_Location, intY_Location)
        Next i
```

I made some changes to place the labels from right to left and they all show as needed. Anyone know why ?  Here is the code

```
            '// Start with Row to show column numbers
        For i = intColumnCount To 0 Step -1

            intX_Location = (50 * i) + intPixel_Width '+ (intSpacer * i) + (intPixel_Width / 2) '//Offset
            intY_Location = 10 '(i * intY) + (intSpacer * i) + (intPixel_Width / 2)

            Panel1.Controls.Add(labels(i))
            labels(i).Location = New Point(intX_Location, intY_Location)

        Next i
```

Since the labels will have new locations depending on the user I also added code to remove labels from panel each time there is an update. This will refresh labels location and properties. I also added the label width which solved the issue I was having with over write.

```
        For i = 0 To 100
        Panel1.Controls.Remove(labels(i))
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 100
        labels(i) = New Label
        labels(i).Width = 10
        labels(i).Text = i.ToString() + 1
        labels(i).Name = "labelControl" + i.ToString()
        '    Panel1.Controls.Add(labels(i))
    Next i
```

Comment: can you right your code before your for loop? it seems you only creating one label?

Comment: I added the code where I create 100 labels. I did try to define all the labels before loop but it did not make a difference. It seems the labels overwrite each other but the labels are only 1 chr long.

Comment: In the code you've posted, you have a loop that creates 101 `Label`s, not 100, and it doesn't set the `Location` of them at all.  If you expect to put a `Label` in a `Location` then you have to actually set the `Location` of that `Label`.

Comment: I updated the post as it in in my code the loop to create the label is first but in this post it was added at the end to explain Dr. stitch question. 100 or 101 is not an issue. The issue is that if I don't  change Y axis only label 1 shows. After more testing I find if I add more spaces(chrs) to the label "12345678" I see all labels but 2 through end but I see only "678"

Comment: Is your intention to overlap the text?  That will end up looking like a splotchy blur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete working example.

I do not understand your code. In the first of your loops, you set the text for 10 labels but we do not see where you create them and you commented the Panel1.controls.add.

In the second loop, you create 100 label and add them to your panel but do not set any text (therefore, they will be create empty and invisible).

You need to create your label, set some text, give it a location and size, such at the example below.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
           Dim PanelsText as New list(of string) from 
    {
        "Label 1",
        "Label 2",
        "I am the best Label ever !",
        "Am I a Label ?",
        "Dumb Label",
        "Definitely not a Label",
        "An ordinary label",
        "Bacon Topped label"
    }


    Dim Position as integer = 1
    For each LabelText as string in PanelsText
        Dim Label as New Label() with 
            {
            .Text = labeltext,
            .Location = New point(10,25 * Position),
            .Height = 23,
            .Width = 200
           }


        Panel1.controls.add(Label)
        Position+=1
    Next




End Sub
```

[image: Ultimate label tester] }

-- Horizontal labels --

Following your comment, I now understand you have trouble with horizontal label placement. In order for it to work, you need to include the label width in your calculation for placing the labels. Otherwise, labels are not transparent. A label using 100 pixel width will hide other label under that 100 px, even if the label make use of only 10 of these pixels.

Take for example this code.

```
private sub PopulateLabels()
      Static InitialPaddingX As Integer = 10
    Static InitialPaddingY As Integer = 15
    Static LabelWidth As Integer = 150
    Static LabelHeight As Integer = 23
    Static LabelPaddingX = 5
    Static LabelPaddingY = 5

    Dim PanelsText As New List(Of String) From
{
 "Label 1",
 "Label 2",
 "I am the best Label ever !",
 "Am I a Label ?",
 "Dumb Label",
 "Definitely not a Label",
 "An ordinary label",
 "Bacon Topped label"
}

    Dim Column As Integer = 0
    Dim Row As Integer = 0
    For Each LabelText As String In PanelsText
        Dim Label As New Label()
        With Label
            .Text = LabelText
            .Size = New Size(LabelWidth, LabelHeight)
            .Left = InitialPaddingX + (Column * LabelWidth + LabelPaddingX)
            .Top = InitialPaddingY + (Row & LabelHeight + LabelPaddingY)
        End With

        Panel1.Controls.Add(Label)

        If Column = 2 Then
            Column = -1
            Row += 1
        End If
        Column += 1

    Next
End sub
```

[image: Ultimate Label tester - Now with horizontal feature]

Comment: Try with constant Y and change  only X .  /  Location = New point(25 * Position,10),

Comment: You need to take in consideration the widths of the labels then. 
See my updated answer.

Comment: Width was the answer. I set to 10 on all labels and they display fine. All labels are only 2 characters long. You got my upvote.